# Autofilter Combo Box for ASP.Net form

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I need a control similar to the `SharePoint:LookupField`, but bindable to any data source.
(i.e. dropdown box that allows typing and filters the items based on what is typed so far)
Preferably, same look and feel as the `LookupField`.
Any recommendations?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want AJAX:
 [AutoComplete](http://www.asp.net/AJAX/AjaxControlToolkit/Samples/AutoComplete/AutoComplete.aspx)